# In SPSS two factor ANOVA, how to compare control groups across other factors?

Tags: anova, spss, post-hoc

I have two factors: **Brainregion (4 levels)** and  **Group (5 levels)**.
Glutamate is my dependent variable.

I am running General Linear Models in SPSS (two factor ANOVA).

Can I get the output in such a way that:
I can compare means (post-hoc test) of control with other levels such as alcohol, EW etc. (Group) across CC, CB etc. (Brainregion)?